# How can I change the corner of a widget in my html code?

Tags: html, widget, location, chat

I have this html code, the chat widget is located at top-left corner of the page
I want to change that to bottom-left

I have tried to load the chat window in an `<iframe>`, it won't load. also i tried to change its location using `<div>` that doesn't work either.

```html
<script id="cid0020000248902945622" data-cfasync="false" async src="https://st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 25%;height: 80%;">
  {
    "handle": "eurousd",
    "arch": "js",
    "styles": { "a": "3366ff", "b": 78, "c": "000000", "d": "000000", "f": 78, "i": 78, "k": "3366ff", "l": "3366ff", "m": "3366ff", "o": 78, "p": "10", "q": "3366ff", "r": 78, "ab": false, "surl": 0, "allowpm": 0, "fwtickm": 1 }
  }
</script>
```

I tried to put my script into following tag:

```
<iframe src="http://eurousd.chatango.com/" style="height:80%;width:25%;position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;"></iframe>
```

the iframe appears but no chat widget is in it!

Comment: I made you a snippet. I think you need some container on the page - the snippet will not run here at SO because it is using cookies

Comment: I tried to put my script into following tag: <iframe src="http://eurousd.chatango.com/" style="height:80%;width:25%;position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;"> </iframe> the iframe appears but no chat widget is in it!

Comment: You cannot load chatango into your frame

Comment: Save the script tag that works in a page on your server, `chat.html` and load it using `<iframe src="chat.html" style="height:80%;width:25%;position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;"></iframe>`

Comment: Yeah, that worked!

Answer (score 2):

Such a widget normally uses document.write or other methods, so save the script tag that works in a page on your server, `chat.html` and load it using

```
<iframe src="chat.html" style="height:80%;width:25%;position:absolute;bottom:0px;left:0px;"></iframe>
```